# Components Render then Disappear

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I have a relatively simple component which renders properly on iOS but not Android. The component appears to render then the top 1/2 of the screen fades away. I'm sure the component is rendered but it appears the subcomponents are fading out or being covered by something. Given that the animation which occurs (quickly) looks like a fade, I think the components are still there.

The component is instantiated by a component which is created by react-navigation as a tab. This component has native-base components. The navigation.push() instantiates a react-native based component. All of the data required to render is in this.state object. Debugging reveals nothing.

Switching to another tab then back resolves the problem. Forcing re-rendering() in the event handler when the tab is focused has no effect.

I'm stumped.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Container,
  Content,
  Body,
  Header,
  Left,
  Right,
  Thumbnail,
  ListItem,
  List,
  Text,
  Button,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Card,
  CardItem,
} from 'native-base';

import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';

export default class UnitDetailScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Unit Details',
      headerRight: <Button onPress={
        () => {
          navigation.navigate(
            'UnitInstallation',
            { item: navigation.getParam('item') }
          )
        }
      }>
        <Text>Edit</Text>
      </Button>,
    }
  };

  state = {
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const item = navigation.getParam('item');
    this.setState({ item: item, navigation: navigation });
  }

  getBatteryImage(item) {
    return { uri: 'battery-green.png' };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.item === undefined) {
      return <Text>loading...</Text>;
    }

    // ok, now this is really wierd... the item is actually pointing to a row when this method called so we can't use getParam('item')
    const rowStyle = {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      marginLeft: 10,
      marginRight: 10,
      padding: 10,
      borderBottomColor: '#888'
    };

    const noPhoto = { uri: 'no-photo.png' }

    return <Container>
      <Content>
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
            <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={noPhoto} />
              <Body>
                <Text>Big Bad Machine</Text>
                <Text note>The Lab</Text>
              </Body>
            </Left>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
        <Card>
          <CardItem bordered>
            <Image style={{
              flex: 1,
              height: 30,
              width: undefined,
              resizeMode: 'contain'
            }} source={this.getBatteryImage(this.state.item)} />
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Installed</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>{this.state.item.unit.installDate}</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Model</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>The model</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Serial</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>{this.state.item.unit.serialNumber}</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Purchased</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>{this.state.item.unit.purchaseDate}</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Installation</Text></Left>
            <Right>
              <Thumbnail square source={noPhoto} />
            </Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>QR Code</Text></Left>
            <QRCode
              value={this.state.item.unit.id}
              size={80}
            />
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Serial</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>{this.state.item.unit.serialNumber}</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left><Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>ID</Text></Left>
            <Right><Text>{this.state.item.unit.id}</Text></Right>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </Content>
      <Footer>
        <FooterTab>
          <Button bordered light>
            <Text>Photos/Notes</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button bordered light>
            <Text>Installation Media</Text>
          </Button>
        </FooterTab>
      </Footer>
    </Container>
  }
}
```

Initial render:
[image: Render 1]

Navigate away:
[image]

Navigate back:
[image]

Comment: Please add images and code. It is very hard debugging in our minds with what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry... it was difficult to find an excerpt to post. I rebuilt the component using native-base without any react-native components. I'm am rendering a QRCode using: react-native-qrcode, this appears to be the component causing the problem. I'll post images and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem using the SVG version of the component:

```
npm install react-native-qrcode-svg --save
```

The props to supply are the same for my application. This solved the problem.